# HERE maps: show both clustered and not clustered points

Tags: here-api

My goal is to display a group of clustered data points and one data point of different nature that never goes to a cluster in the same layer, so they all can received hover mouse events.

Is it possible to tell `H.clustering.Provider` to always exclude some points from clusters, or create a custom `H.map.provider.ObjectProvider` that can do it?

P. S.
I tried creating two layers and setting `pointer-events: none` for them in CSS to catch hover events by all points, it worked but made the map too slow to use.

**Update**

Here is a demo code, the goal is to get a hover rectangle for both markers with a condition that the first market should never be included to a cluster

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-clustering.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style>
        svg:hover {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapContainer"/>
    <script>
        var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            'app_id': 'my id',
            'app_code': 'my code'
        });

        var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
        var map = new H.Map(
            document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
            defaultLayers.normal.map,
            {
                zoom: 10,
                center: { lat: 51.5, lng: 13.4 }
            });

        //this marker should not go to clusters
        var marker = new H.map.DomMarker({ lat: 51.5, lng: 13.4 });
        map.addObject(marker);

        //this marker should go to clusters if there is more data points
        var dataPoints = [];
        dataPoints.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(51.5, 13.45));
        var theme = 
        {
            getClusterPresentation: function(cluster){
                return new H.map.DomMarker(cluster.getPosition(), {});
            },
            getNoisePresentation: function(point){
                return new H.map.DomMarker(point.getPosition(), {});
            }
        }
        var clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
            theme: theme,
        });
        var layer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider);
        map.addLayer(layer);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide your code snippet and the Here API you are using to achieve this.

Comment: @here-developer-support, I have update the question with a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows a cluster provider initialized with the parameters eps and minWeight. **eps** holds the value of the radius within which data points are considered for clustering, while **minWeight** holds the cumulative weight that points lying close to another must reach or exceed to be clustered. The value of minWeight is 3 in the example, which means that three points, each with the weight of one or two data points with the weight of 2 and 1, respectively, form a cluster. This will reduce the time of rendering the page. Also please refer the new documentation :

> https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/clustering/marker-clustering

```
var clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
  min: 4,
  max: 10,
  clusteringOptions: {
  eps: 32,
  minWeight: 3
  }
});
```